# Detect only website traffic, ignore email clients etc

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

working in Laravel / PHP and have built a bespoke tracking system to track visits to our sites.

The issue currently is that email clients / Mailchimp will trigger a visit to be tracked when they send / the email is previewed by the client.

I guess email clients do some sort of link fetching even if the user doesn't click.

I'm already using a Crawler detection package (https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect) but would rather a better way of only tracking genuine visits to our site.

Is there anything clever that can be done to really know if the page was loaded via a browser? E.g, something I can only show on the page if it's not from a crawler or not browser etc.

Comment: So do the same as that crawler, analyse sent headers to see if it's coming from specific user agent

Comment: Just keep in mind that I can copy exact same request made from browser and do it via e.g. Postman - everything can be faked

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, email clients don’t do link fetching, some links are direct unsubscribes which would cause havoc. When sending, some emails clients, notably Outlook on the web, will generate a preview which does cause an HTTP request to go to the server. On my iPad I can click and hold a link to get a mini-preview, would you want to block that, too? I would generally say that except for bots, this kind of traffic should be minimal enough that it can be ignored.

Comment: how is your tracking working via a queue or ? And are you tracking organic traffic or?

Comment: @leo It's an API call to our tracking tool thats called via middleware and queued on the server to add the data to database.

Comment: @ChrisHaas At the moment, every email that Mailchimp sends results in 2 visits for each link and they are all within the same second. Ideally wouldn't want the visit logged for previews no.

Comment: So do you think the _send_ is causing it? Like if you send to test@example.com you’d get two visits on each link, even though there’s no mailbox on that account? Or is it on the client side?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Good test, just sent the email through Mailchimp and it fired off two 'visits' even before it hit my inbox.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The crawler package I use works but I've checked the user agent for the visits from Mailchimp sending and they dont look like bots or crawlers: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36

Comment: Can you check if Mailchimp is "wrapping" your links with click-tracking code? If so, their click tracker might be testing if the links are valid, although I'd expect a HEAD request for that. Also, is it possible that you've got an errant `<img>` tag in the email that points to your server and is technically 404'ing but your tracker is picking it up?

Comment: if you are using blades to generate mail content when preview is being generated href links in that email are going to generate traffic, you could edit mail links to include an extra url param, like &source=email and filter the traffic based on that param in your middleware before pushing to the queue. 

Optionally if you use a different master blade from your mail rendering temp. You can set a cookie in master template and simply check in middleware `$request->hasCookie('organic_traffic')` before pushing to the queue